# Cannot hide a folder using java's Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, runtime.exec

```
if(!dataFolder.isHidden())
          if(System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase()
                              .indexOf("windows") > -1){
             String command = "attrib +h -r -s " + dataFolder.getAbsolutePath();
             Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
             System.out.println(command);
          }
```

I'm running the code above, and there is no way I can get it to work. I want to make the ".data" folder hidden, not read-only and not a system folder, but it gets created visible and read-only.

This is the output of the System.out.println line:

```
attrib +h -r -s D:\eclipse\bin\.data
```

I'm also unable to use the exitValue() method of the process because it always complains about:

```
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the [`Process.waitFor()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) method first.  This method will block until the `attrib` process has exited.  A process will not have an exit code until it has finished.

Comment: Thank you, using that I got to see the result from exitValue (which is 0), but I still can't hide the folder. 0 means OK, doesn't it?

Comment: @osr yes 0 means success.  Check that the dir actually has the hidd attribute through explorer properties or dir.

Comment: yes I checked and it's so not hidden, I'm wondering  if it has something to do with that folder being inside the bin directory. Maybe eclipse touches it an returns it to a visible state right after when the program runs. I'm going with that...